# Generating unsigned, release apk with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I need to generate an unsigned, **release** APK (where someone else will then sign it and release it to the store- with the someone else handling the keys and everything else). My problem is that Android Studio throws an error whenever I try to build:

```
app-flavorUnsigned-release-unsigned.apk is not signed. Please configure the signing information for the selected flavor using the Project Structure dialog.
```

I've tried several, previous methods:

- Failed at creating an Artifact (can't find any menus with "Artifacts" anywhere, although for editing configurations I found the option to choose a custom Artifact) [**Probably best bet**]
- Creating an empty signing config
- Creating a custom flavor
- Using the terminal to run `gradle assemble` or `gradle assembleRelease` (which fail due to one of my important module libraries trying to be built)

Here is my current [app's] build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        unsigned {
            storePassword = ""
            keyAlias = ""
            keyPassword = ""
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hiddenForClientPrivacy"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.unsigned
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.unsigned
        }
        unsignedBuild {
            debuggable false
            versionNameSuffix '-unsigned'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.unsigned
        }
        debug {

        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        flavorUnsigned {
            versionCode = 1;
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile project(':SlidingMenu')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.verticalviewpager:library:19.0.1'
}
```

Thank you for any and all help.

Post-Help Edit:
As the marked accepted answer shows, I had to clear out the release block. Furthermore, I was clicking on the "Run" button- which should appropriately show an error as I can't run an unsigned release apk on an emulator or device. The accepted answer describes everything.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the `release` build type, don't specify a `signingConfig` at all, and your build won't be signed. Release builds don't pick up the default signing config that debug builds get, so it should work for those.

There's a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/adt-dev/unsigned$20apk/adt-dev/XECqmZgIARM/IA6jymn_Z3wJ) on the adt-dev mailing list about it.

Bear in mind that to build from Android Studio, you'll need to go to the Gradle tasks window and choose the `assembleRelease` task; normal builds via "Make Project" don't actually build the final APK.

Comment: Won't it use the debug certificate/signature instead then?

Comment: Not for release builds. Try it out and make sure it works; I haven't tested it but I have it on good authority it works :)

Comment: Android Studio is still preventing me (maybe it's an annoying block with the new version?). My buildType for release is this: "        release {

        }". [Cleaned the project, synced gradle, and such as well]

Comment: That should work...you're replacing your existing `release` block, right? That will remove the proguard config stuff, but you don't have proguard enabled so it won't affect you yet.

Comment: Yup- I simply deleted it all (including the proguard part). Oh wait... I think I know... I'm clicking the Run button... So it can't load it on anything. However, "Make Project" runs, but there is no apk in the outputs directory. Sorry for overlooking something so important.

Comment: Make project doesn't actually build the APK, which is super-annoying, I know. You can go to your Gradle tasks window and choose `assembleRelease`, or you can build from the command line.

Comment: Oh wow. It worked perfectly! I couldn't build it from the command line as mentioned earlier (due to some gradle-based configuration error with one of my modules), but from within the IDE it worked like a charm. I'll go edit my question to add in these details. Can you add the small part about building it correctly so I can mark your answer as correct?

Comment: The task is now called "assemble" and is under the Gradle tasks at Android/app/Tasks/build/assemble. This puts the APK in the folder at app/build/output/apk/release/

Answer (score 24):

Actually you can build an unsigned .APK just by building it:

To generate it, on the left side of the Android Studio, there is a **Build Variants** menu (maybe written *vertically*). Click it.

The Build Variants window tab has appeared, click **debug** and change it by **release**.

Rebuild your project application **> Build > Rebuild Project**.

Then click **Run**, a new window has appeared, click **Run > Continue anyway > Choose the device you want to run with > OK**.

The application won't work on your device but the release build version, of your .apk, will be generated into the same directory as your debug ones:

- C:\ANDROID_PROJECT_DIRECTORY\app\build\outputs\apk\

You can note that the name is **app-release-unsigned.apk** and it was exactly what we wanted to have.

More information on this [tutorial website](https://www.badprog.com/android-android-studio-generating-an-unsigned-release-apk).

Comment: After change debug to release step, the later steps can be simplified to `Build` -> `Build APK` and you will get the unsigned apk in that directory.

Comment: Doesn't work, it won't let me run unless key is set

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the same thing (because app signing is handled elsewhere) and I simply rebuilt the project.

To generate an **unsigned release apk**, select a release version in the **Build Variants** menu.

Note: You may get a red cross in your app configuration on the top menu, ignore it.

Rebuild your project application **Build > Rebuild Project**.

You will find your app-release-unsigned.apk in:

- ~\app\build\outputs\apk\release\

Note: If you need to create other versions, save the generated apk because subsequent rebuilds will overwrite the current apk(...don't be like me).