# Unaligned apk and Unsigned apk Similarities and differences

Tags: android, android-studio

I have googled merely found below:

[Are unaligned android APK's the same as unsigned APK? need to generate release apk that is unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855540/are-unaligned-android-apks-the-same-as-unsigned-apk-need-to-generate-release-a)

Only put emphasis on the differences but not  Similarities .

Any explanation is appreciated!

Comment: 'I have google exhausted,but have not find a clear answer'. Given the fact that your question is this short, I highly doubt it. Please share results of your research!

Comment: did you mean Unaligned Signed APK and Aligned Signed APK ??

Comment: @PriyaJagtap I don't know if unaligned apk if signed.

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE thx,reedit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unaligned Apk is an intermediate Apk.

When we run app, first, the unaligned apk is generated. after that , the unaligned apk gets aligned and produces the aligned apk which is the your app-debug.apk.

For more information read documentaion [click here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)

Comment: align then sign is great!

Answer (score 0):

`Unaligned APK` refers to how the data is structured within the APK (zip file). A utility called `zipalign` modifies the APK to align data in a way that is optimized for readers. Unaligned simply skips the zipalign stage. It has nothing to do with APK signing.
The `unaligned apk` is just an intermediate apk. First, the unaligned apk is generated. Then, the unaligned apk gets aligned and produces the aligned apk which is the app-debug.apk.

`Signing Android apps` is just like signing any other application; it provides the user with some level of assurance that the code hasn't been tampered with since you released it.

"Unsigned apps" should be usable generally but do require lowering the security level.

For more details :- 
[Are unaligned android APK's the same as unsigned APK? need to generate release apk that is unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855540/are-unaligned-android-apks-the-same-as-unsigned-apk-need-to-generate-release-a)

[Difference between app-debug.apk and app-debug-unaligned.apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366905/difference-between-app-debug-apk-and-app-debug-unaligned-apk)

[why unaligned apk is needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058210/why-unaligned-apk-is-needed)

Comment: You answer is right,but not I wanted.You not show their relationship.Align process is before sign process.Thank you same time.