# how can I create apk release without signing

Tags: android, google-play, apk, release

how can I create apk release without signing in my project ?
[image]

Comment: All installable APKs are signed, whether they are build using `debug`, `release`, or some other build type.

Comment: @CommonsWare / so it is impossible to do it?

Comment: I think that there are Gradle tasks that can create an APK but not do the signing part. However, those APKs cannot be installed until they are signed, as Android will reject unsigned APKs.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by not signing it? Note that as mentioned above debug APK's are signed by a debug key unique to your machine that is auto generated.

Answer (score 23):

You can use debug signingConfig as release signingConfig, just add this line to release build type:

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
```

Like this:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            //...
        }

        debug {
            //...
        }
    }
```

Now set app module **Build Variant** to **Release** and generate release apk or run using android studio directly.

Comment: for kotlin dsl use `signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("debug")`

Answer (score 9):

Here in below image select your app then follow these steps (used Android studio 3.2.1):

1) Build-> Edit build type-> (app)select release--> Ok

2) Build-> Select build Variant-> change from build to release(As shown in first image) --> It will Build gradle and update indices (Let it complete)

3) Build -> Build bundles/apks --> Build apks --> This wil start making release apk without signing and also you refer second image for the tasks running while bulding release APK.
It would take time if you have used the Pro-guard (due to classes and resources being transformed during this step). After last task "**app:assembleRlease**", your release APK will get generated.

[image]

[image]

Also, refer this link for more [Generating unsigned, release apk with Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321979/generating-unsigned-release-apk-with-android-studio)